# Webpage automation using Selenium fails inside a VSTO (PowerPoint) project

Tags: visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, vsto, console-application, powerpoint

I made a simple console app which works fine for opening a webpage inside IE.
Following is the code for same

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;

namespace webAutoMationSelenium
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:8080/t7s3upload/upload.jsp");
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have a VSTO (PowerpPint) project, and on click of a button on ribbon I have put the same code, but it breaks with "FatalExecutionEngineError Occurred" error.

Please see the screen-shot for exact error and the piece of code

[image]

Following is the complete error details:
[image]

If this can help (note sure though):
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4180
Is it due to unmanaged code, then how should I fix it

Comment: The most important information is hidden on your picture "The error code is...". What is the code?

Comment: @AlexButenko: I have updated the question with error details window. Let me know if I should provide any other required detail.
Regards